# Flutter archive: create password-protected zip

Tags: android, ios, flutter, zip, archive

I am using [archive](https://pub.dev/packages/archive) library to archive folder in Flutter. I want to create password protected zip, but I didn't find any parameter or method in [archive](https://pub.dev/packages/archive) library.

Please suggest me any link or example to create zip with password.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you found a solution for that?
Thanks!

Comment: No. Using channel I have achieved this.

Comment: Oh, Channel? What do you mean? Thanks again!

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels